# Installed ZF on server, uploaded application, now receiving 404?

Tags: php, zend-framework, iis

I have recently installed the Zend Framework on our server running IIS7 & PHP5.

I have uploaded an application to the server built using the ZF.

The Index controller renders fine; the `Zend_Form` login form is built as expected, which implies that the ZF install is working OK.

However, when the login is performed, and `$this->_helper->redirector('index', 'reseller');` is called in the Index controller, I receive a 404 message from the server!

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Many thanks

EDIT:

The URL I'm being redirected to is (which is correct):

```
http://mydomain.co.uk/public/reseller
```

Physical path requested (this may be the problem!):

```
D:\vhosts\mydomain.co.uk\httpdocs\public\reseller
```

(This is the 'reseller' controller, 'index' action, that is part of the application).
[image]

Comment: Could you include the URL you are being redirected to? This is actually pretty handy information if we'd have to determine why a 404 is showing :)

Comment: :) Good point Aron - post updated!

Answer (score 0):

This was solved through adding a web.config XML file into the public directory of the application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 1">
                    <match url="^[\w/\%]*(?:\.(?!(?:js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|html)$)[\w\%]*$)?" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.php" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>-->
<configuration>
     <system.webServer>
         <rewrite>
             <rules>
                 <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
                     <match url="^.*$" />
                     <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                         <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}"
                             matchType="IsFile" pattern=""
                             ignoreCase="false" />
                         <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}"
                             matchType="IsDirectory"
                             pattern="" ignoreCase="false" />
                     </conditions>
                     <action type="None" />
                 </rule>
                 <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
                     <match url="^.*$" />
                     <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
                 </rule>
             </rules>
         </rewrite>
     </system.webServer>
```